# Trying to get Edimax EW-7822UAC USB wireless adapter driver to install

Tags: wireless, drivers, extract

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, which seems unfortunate, as the instructions in the package are written for 12.04. So, like a trooper, I try to follow the instructions anyway. The first block I hit is in the fifth step, where it asks me to extract a driver... Now, it becomes clear that these instructions were pretty poorly made, as the line of code they give isn't the same as the image they provide:

```
tar vxf 2011_0427_RT3572_Linux_STA_v.2.5.0.0.DP.bz2
```

and then

```
tar vxzf rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.0_6952.20130315.tar.gz
```

Neither if these work. Also, the file name itself is rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517_fix_led.tar.gz
Not sure how relevant that is, but I think it might be useful.

Comment: .gz indicates to me a file that should be extracted with gzip

Comment: I saw that post mentioned above, but it didn't help me. So, what about this gzip deal?